# ng dialog triggers not executes called function instructions

Tags: angularjs

I need ng-dialog , based on the value returned from ngdialog i need to execute some instructions. after the ng dialog triggers, it stops to execute to the remaining instructions in called function.

```
$scope.dialogOpen(){
 ngDialog.open({' template:'<div>'+
                            '<p class="">Do u want to save the settings?</p>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div>'+
                            '<button ng-click="confirms(true)">Save</button>'+
                            '<button ng-click="confirms(false)">Don\'t Save </button>'+
                        '</div>',
                    plain: true,
                    showClose:false,
                    scope:$scope
});
};
$scope.confirms=function(param){
$scope.confirmValue=param;
};
$scope.getconfirm=function(){
        $scope.dialogOpen();
if(confirmValue){
//do something
}else{
//do something
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the statements you want in the function calls invoked upon click itself.

`($scope.confirms())` because the statements followed by the ngDialog open will be executed after completing the open operation, it won't wait for the response by the user.

So you can use the function calls to execute the desired statements

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the explanation you provide?